# How can I indent inline Javascript in web-mode?

Tags: emacs

I'm typing away a little html/js in Emacs using web-mode.el

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
         var i = 0;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I find that the line after `<script>` is indented by just 1 space.

My `.emacs` contains:

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . web-mode))

(setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-attr-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-attr-value-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-indentless-elements 4)
(setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-sql-indent-offset 4)
```

1. Which variable did I miss?
2. How could I have found the answer myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable you are looking for is `web-mode-script-padding`:

```
(setq web-mode-script-padding 4)
```

If you want to do the same for `<style>` tags, you can use `web-mode-style-padding`:

```
(setq web-mode-style-padding 4)
```

Finally, if you want to do the same for inline server-side code, such as PHP, you can use `web-mode-block-padding`:

```
(setq web-mode-block-padding 4)
```

This information can be found at [Web Mode's homepage](http://web-mode.org), under the **Customization** section. (To be fair, that page doesn't contain an example of what this code does, so it would be easy to skip over it.)

Comment: Great, but the URL you cite is now singularly unhelpful. So much so that it's for sale. :-)

Comment: Oops. Not sure how that typo slipped by when I copy-pasted the link. Of course this happens the *one time* that I don't double check my links. (Fixed now.)

Comment: Thanks. I see that `web-mode-block-padding` finish off the trio, but after trying on a few html files, I see no difference in the indentation. For a future discovery then.

Comment: That would be for server-side code, such as PHP. I've edited my answer for completeness.